# Button That Copy And Pastes

Tags: c#, button

I want to make a button so when you click it it copys something to your clipboard with c# for example:
 I click the button and I press ctrl + v and it types out something
I have tried my.clipboard.settext ("text") and some other commands but i cant figure it out.
The button doesnt have any code but the default.
https://gyazo.com/32d07e4d7a5b67fbd78b8c5956026023

I learned how to do it you type this:

string script = Properties.Resources.STRINGNAME.ToString();
Clipboard.SetText(script);

then go to project>resources>add string> put the stuff you want to copy there.

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: what, google doesn't work today?

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to find the problem? Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `Clipboard.SetDataObject(yourStringHere);` is what you are looking for.

Clipboard.SetDataObject method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs5ebdfz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It doesnt copy the word I think I put the scrip it wrong

Comment: I changed my answer to use SetDataObject instead of SetText, since that can have issues.

Comment: @AidanAbello - *It doesnt copy the word I think I put the scrip it wrong* - in that case, I would suggest asking a new question and providing a [mcve] showing the code that does not work.  We're more likely to be able to help you if you show what you have tried.  See [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/.  And if this answer worked after all please do [mark it as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147531).